# Add_Click function from XAML only parses some commands?

Tags: powershell, xaml

This is an extremely strange issue- I have some Powershell code and a XAML GUI I made with Visual Studio for a fairly basic app for users. I'm fairly experienced with Powershell, but completely new to XAML.

Here's the code snippet:

`

```
$var_RKH.Add_Click({
    $targetSite = $RKH
    $var_TargetSite.Content = "Rock Hill"
})
```

`

Somehow, $targetSite is still null after this click event. I've confirmed the var $RKH contains the needed data. In another click event on another button, I copy-pasted that same line and it works. However, what's absolutely twisted my brain is- the third line works. The $var_TargetSite.Content variable is correctly updated.

So the click event is definitely firing, the second line just gets completely skipped somehow, and the third line works fine. On other click events, the exact same code works fine. I must be missing something very simple because this is absolutely twisting my brain.

Comment: You experience a scoping issue. Inside the scripblock, variable `$targetSite` is just a new, local variable that exists only in the scripblock. Use as `$script:targetSite`

Comment: @Theo well that bends my brain a bit. This is all within the same script, why would that specific variable not be available at this scope? I have a C# background so this is extremely odd to me- $targetSite is defined within this script and it's being set in a function within this script. How is it out of scope? That does indeed resolve the problem, I just don't understand why.

Comment: See: [Powershell: WPF action on second button click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48469149/powershell-wpf-action-on-second-button-click) and [Powershell with GUI will not set variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14740527/1701026)

Answer (score 0):

Script blocks aren't really scopes. They're script blocks and do not inherit from enclosing scope. Instead, you pass values into it just like you would for a thread in C#. This can get confusing because both scopes and script blocks get the `{}` delimiter -- they're not the same though and not interchangeable either:

```
[scriptblock]$Sb = {'This is a test'}
if($true) $sb
```

will throw a ParserError exception rather than print 'this is a test'.

Please be *very* careful about "sideloading" variables, especially with WPF; there is a high degree of multithread in any WPF application and you literally don't know who is going to access what when.

If you can, try to resolve the value of $RKH inside the script block rather than try to force it in.

Or you could implement code-behind for the XAML and put both .xaml and .xaml.cs in an assembly, then use that in PS.